# Eclipse CDT issue with building project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting a strange problem with my C/C++ dev environment. I had installed gcc, g++ on my linux box(ubuntu 14.04). 
With the hello world program being built on my system I'm getting this error:

```
make all 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [src/Banker's.o] Error 2
```

has anyone encountered to this problem before could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the name of the file you're trying to compile: `Banker's.c`. Rename the source to `Bankers.c` without the single quote in it.

```
mv src/"Banker's.c" src/"Bankers.c"
```